# Computing $\mathrm{Tor}_{i}^{R}(M,(x^k))$, where $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, functors

Computing $\mathrm{Tor}_{i}^{R}(M,(x^k))$, where $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$.

Let $M$ be any $R$ module. $k$ and $n$ are positive integers. I think I have a valid free resolution for $(x^k)$ given by

$$ \cdots \overset{\cdot x^{n-k}}{\longrightarrow}R\overset{\cdot x^k}{\longrightarrow}R\overset{\cdot x^{n-k}}{\longrightarrow}R\overset{\cdot x^k}{\longrightarrow} (x^k)\longrightarrow0$$

We then tensor with $M$ to and take homology. This is where I am running into trouble. With the complex$$ \cdots \overset{1\otimes \cdot x^{n-k}}{\longrightarrow}M\overset{1\otimes\cdot x^k}{\longrightarrow}M\overset{1\otimes\cdot x^{n-k}}{\longrightarrow}M\longrightarrow0$$

I know I should get that $\mathrm{Tor}_{0}^{R}(M,(x^k))=M\otimes_R(x^k)$, but I am having trouble computing that directly. I get $M/(M\otimes (x^{n-k}))$ which I am not sure how to make sense of. Similarly, describing the kernels of these maps is eluding me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As $(x^k)\cong R/(x^{n-k})$ as $R$ modules, then the tensor product
$$M\otimes_R(x^k)\cong M\otimes_R R/(x^{n-k})\cong M/(x^{n-k}M).$$
The $\text{Tor}_0^R$ as you compute it is the cokernel of
$\cdot x^{n-k}$ on $M$, that is $M/(x^{n-k}M)$, so it does all check out.

Comment: Does this mean all the higher homology is zero? It seems the kernel for example of $M\overset{1\otimes\cdot x^k}{\longrightarrow}M$ is given by $M\otimes (x^{n-k})$ which is the image of the map $M\overset{1\otimes\cdot x^{n-k}}{\longrightarrow}M$

Comment: @irh The $\text{Tor}_1^R$ is the kernel of $x^{n-k}$ factored by the image of $x^k$. If say $k=1$ and $n=2$ this will be nonzero for say $M=R/(x)$.

Comment: So, is there a better way to characterize the kernel of the map $x^{n-k}$ other than $\{m|x^{n-k}m=0\}$? Sorry for my incompetence here, I just don't see it.